# Is my iron cast pan properly cleaned?

Tags: cleaning, cast-iron, pan

As you can see, there is a black area on one half of my iron cast pan:

[image]

Is this normal? Or I'm not cleaning my pan properly? I did it with salt and a sponge (while the pan was hot).

Comment: Hard to tell from you pic.  It looks good to me. However, stains are covered by the suggested duplicate.